# How to run my macro in an excel application created by vba Access 2016

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an excel application that is created by VBA access. I want to create a certain macro in this excel application so that certain cells (also determined by vba access) can call it.

Say I want to add a macro called myMacro with three integer parameters. I know I have to create it like so somewhere:

```
Function myMacro(A as Integer, B as Integer, C as Integer) As Double
   ...
End Function
```

And I know to call that I have to have my program write something like this into the cell:

```
=myMacro(1,2,3)
```

But how do I make this macro actually known to the excel application?
My gut feeling is that it has to be inside of the excel's application vba code but is there anyway to do this from the Excel.Application object in vba access?

Comment: All explained here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Thanks but is this article outdated? I am using access 2016 (just added in my post)  and I already do not see the "Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility 5.3" reference in the references list.

Comment: I have Excel 2016 and that reference is still available.

Comment: Oh okay. I was unaware that it was a reference I had to add in Excel. I was looking in VBA Access. And since I am creating this excel app programatically, I have to add the reference programatically. Is this correct?